# Scrolling input is unresponsive in Chrome and Chromium apps

Tags: kubuntu, google-chrome, 19.04, scrolling, mouse-wheel

I am running Kubuntu 19.04. I use a Logitech mouse that has a scroll wheel. The scroll wheel usually works fine, but occasionally when I'm scrolling a lot the scrolling will get "stuck" and stop working. It will stay stuck until I move the mouse. It typically happens when I am trying to scroll really fast.

How might I go about fixing this behavior? I use the exact same mouse in Windows and I don't have any problems, so I don't believe it is a hardware issue.

Comment: make sure the transmitter is not to far away and is not hidden on the back of your computer

Comment: It's a wired mouse.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem when you want to? Does it happen for different applications, or only for one specific application and if so, which application?

Comment: Hmm, now that I play around with it, I think it is only happening in Chrome and apps that use Chrome like Slack. I can't reproduce it in Firefox or native apps like Konsole.

Comment: @asmeurer , could you edit and update the question. Comments are not good for important info, they can be removed/cleaned later.

Comment: If it only happens in Chrome then that is very important info. Try to verify if that is really the case, and update the question to include that info.

Answer (score 1):

1. Goto `chrome://flags/`
2. Search for: *scroll*
3. Try diffenrent options of: Smooth Scrolling, Threaded scrolling, Enable lazy frame loading.

Comment: Good idea. I played with it but none of them seem to fix it. I guess this is a bug in Chrome.

Comment: @asmeurer could be but we have nothing to blame it yet . Close every window and try it from command line with `--incognito --enable-logging=stderr --v=1` option to start without extensions , see if it is still hanging while scrolling, also watch for error messages if there are any. Another point, try chrome from new user account, it could be something in current user  profile.

Comment: It still happens and it doesn't seem to print any error messages. The reason I'm guessing it's an issue with the Chromium engine is that it also happens in Slack.

Comment: @asmeurer I can't go far in debugging, it is up to you. here is some info that may help https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/linux_debugging.md You probably need to test last release with current Ubuntu release 19.10 before raising a failure report.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but since on Edge everything was working correctly I played around with flags.

I ended up disabling **Percent-based Scrolling**, now there is no delay between the first "scrooling gesture" on the mouse wheel and the browser.

Hope that helps

Comment: This also worked for me. But he name seems to have changed. I disabled Windows Scrolling Personality